# I want to increase the maximum number of notations of searborn clustermap row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

[image: Please look at the "-" on the right]

There are more than 200 rows, but it seems that there are not even 100 "-"s actually displayed.

How can I use seaborn's clustermap to display the labeling for all rows?

Comment: seaborn usually lets you to set the `yticklabels` argument to range of labels, which are going to be display.